# linux/gcc: ldd functionality from inside a C/C++ program

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, dependencies, ldd

Is there a simple and efficient way to know that a given dynamically linked `ELF` is missing a required .so for it to run, all from the **inside** of a C/C++ program?

I need a program with somewhat similar functionality as `ldd`, without trying to execute the `ELF` to find out the (met/unmet) dependencies in the system. Perhaps asking the ld-linux.so utility via some library? (I'm a newbie in this part of linux =)

> NOTE: reading the source code of `ldd` was not very helpful for my intentions: it seems that `ldd` is in fact forking another process and executing the program.

If it's not possible to know that a program has unmet dependencies without executing it, is there some way to, at least, quickly list the .so's required for that `ELF` all from within my program?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Do you have good reason why not just invoke ldd utility and parse its output? Under linux, such technique is widely used.

Comment: I'd prefer not to call the shell to execute anything else than my own program.. besides, it's not very efficient to fork, start a shell, etc just to try if an executable will run by trial and error.. but yes, I suspect invoking ldd is a good standard choice.

Comment: Sorry, this is a myth. Fork is not at all expensive nowadays and most exec*() calls does not use shell to run a binary. It is easily possible that you will kill more time by diving into ld-linux internals as compared to fork()/exec() overhead for all future invocations together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [ld.so(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so), setting the environment variable `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS` to a non-empty string will give `ldd`-like results (instead of executing the binary or library normally).

```
setenv("LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS", "1", 1);
FILE *ldd = popen("/lib/libz.so");
```

Comment: yes, that will give exactly the same output than ldd (well, with perhaps setting an extra couple of envs more) in fact ldd is nothing else than your code.. but of course, this solution is the same as calling ldd that in turn will call your code.. I was looking for another solution, perhaps querying ld-linux.so in another, more direct way..

Comment: .. and without invoking a shell =)

Comment: Without invoking a shell is easy -- just `fork` and `exec` (`pipe` first if you want output, and `fdopen` if you really want a `FILE *`) instead of `popen`.  This is basically querying `ld-linux.so` without having to hard-code *which* `ld-linux.so`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `dlopen` function? you can use this to load a dynamic library (or, for your case, to ckeck if a library can be loaded).

Having a list of needed libraries is more difficult, take a look to `handle_dynamic` function on [readelf source](http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/elfutils.git?p=elfutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/readelf.c;hb=HEAD)

Comment: that function is interesting, I can see the rpath and another parameters.. I'll investigate further, thanks

Answer (score -1):

What about using ptrace() to trace all open() calls to find all what the program depends on (however, the output includes files,not only libraries).Or maybe filtering the output by the prefix in file name "/lib" helps.