# Retrieve libs runtime

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dynamic-library

I googled a lot without success.

What I need is, if possible, a way to retrieve runtime which dynamic libs are used by the process.

I know [ldd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), but I'm looking for a c coded solution.

The goal is to have processes that, at startup, retrieve info about libs and send them to an information process able to store and show all libs used by my processes.

**EDIT**
Take notes that I'm developing an embedded system, that must be as little (in RootFS footprint terms) as possible.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519684/linux-gcc-ldd-functionality-from-inside-a-c-c-program

Comment: @nnn As far as I can understand is always something to be run on console,  like using `system()`

Comment: Do you have a good reason why you don't want to use `ldd` or similar?

Comment: @skyking to avoid parsing the output of an external program and to avoid enlarging my RootFS with ldd. I missed to write that I'm talking about an embedded system.

Answer (score 2):

You want parse elf-header by your program. Ok, at the end you will got list of NEEDED dependencies for analyzed elf-file only, for example (`readelf -d` output):

```
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)     Shared library: [libcurl.so.4]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)     Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Then you should recursively parse each found library to get their dependencies. This forces to find full path for each library. For doing this you should handle search PATHs for libraries: built-in ld.so and environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. There also can appear `RPATH` field (higher priority search path) in elf structure with special variables, for example:

```
0x0000000f (RPATH) Library rpath: [/usr/lib:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:$ORIGIN]
```

`ldd` is bash script that has much routines and comments, so it can be stripped in minimal size if needed. In usual case it invokes the ld.so (standard dynamic linker) with set variable LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS. That is all. So parse `ldd` output is much comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

What `ldd` does is actually to set `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS` environment variable and execute the program. So actually the `ldd` functionality doesn't require extra footprint to execute.

But you might want to avoid parsing the output. Or maybe you even use another dynamic linker than `ld.so` (which don't respect the `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS` variable).

One solution would be to modify your dynamic linker so that it has an C API interface as well and allow it to report the `.so` files that would should have been loaded.

Comment: Your suggested solution is interesting. Could you elaborate it deeply?