# Check if OpenCV is compiled with GTK support from C++ code

Tags: c++, opencv

My problem is the same as in: 
[OpenCV GTK+2.x error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776053/opencv-gtk2-x-error/43332819#43332819)

I am facing this problem deploying my code in systems where OpenCV is available but has not been installed with GTK support. I have no control over OpenCV installation in these systems.

How can I discriminate where OpenCV is compiled without GTK support from C++ code, possibly without relying on catching exceptions? I would simply avoid calling imshow in these cases.

Comment: something like: `#if defined (HAVE_GTK)` should work. You can check build information also with [getBuildInformation](https://www.learnopencv.com/get-opencv-build-information-getbuildinformation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could check dependencies by executing `ldd opencv-lib` and parse the output using e.g. regex to check for some kind of gtk libs.

Or use this approach: [linux/gcc: ldd functionality from inside a C/C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519684/linux-gcc-ldd-functionality-from-inside-a-c-c-program)

`setenv("LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS", "1", 1);
FILE *ldd = popen("/lib/libz.so");`